# java convert HSSFCell to number

Tags: java, type-conversion, hssf

Could anyone help?
By using that code, I was able to get a value from an Excel field as well. There is a value for a specific column = 5.

```
public Integer  Check4(int b) throws IOException  {
    InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("book.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb     = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);       // first sheet
    HSSFRow row     = sheet.getRow(0);        // first row
    //HSSFCell cell0   = row.getCell((short)a);  // first arg
    HSSFCell cell1   = row.getCell((short)b);  // second arg
    cell1.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    System.out.println("smth "+  cell1);
    return ;

}
```

However, 
The output of the such code is:

```
"smth + 5.0"
```

I'd get it, how to convert the var cell1 5.0 to 5 ?
Math.round, Integer.parseInt() don't, actually, help

Comment: What does Integer.parseInt() return? Exception?

Comment: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (HSSFCell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, solve by (int) Math.round(cell1.getNumericCellValue()))

```
    public Integer  Check4(int b) throws IOException  {
    InputStream myxls = new FileInputStream("book.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook wb     = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);       // first sheet
    HSSFRow row     = sheet.getRow(1);        // first row
    //HSSFCell cell0   = row.getCell((short)a);  // first arg
    HSSFCell cell1   = row.getCell((short)b);  // second arg
    String sell = cell1.toString();
    cell1.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
    System.out.println("smth "+ (int) Math.round(cell1.getNumericCellValue()));
    return  (int) Math.round(cell1.getNumericCellValue());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the string value from the `HSSFCell` before using `Integer.parseInt()`.
Use `Integer.parseInt(cell1.getStringCellValue())`. You can probably use `getNumericCellValue()` but that will return a `double`.